# Ngrx two guards for a route at logout the second doesn't trigger

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-guards

I've got these routes:

```
{
    path: 'admin',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard, AccountGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
    data: { preload: false }
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
    data: { preload: false }
  }
```

At login, both are triggered but when in the admin area I do logout
deleting both auth and account states, redirecting to the auth route if I do login again without refresh only the first is triggered.
I've tried using

```
onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'

runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
```

but I still have the same behavior.

Any ideas?

**NB**
I've also tried putting a simple console.log
in the AccountGuard like

```
canLoad(): Observable<boolean> {console.log('Account)}
```

but in the second login I don't see any message
in the dev tools

Comment: Put a whole code please. What exactly you have in guards. What kind of authentication you using ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the definition from angular website - "`CanLoad` is an Interface that a class can implement to be a guard deciding if children can be loaded".

When the route/child is loaded the `CanLoad` guard returns true and then, once loaded, the guard will not be called again. It's the role of `CanActivate` to do these kind of checks everytime you are navigating to a route. I would suggest to implement `CanActivate` and assign the guard which needs to be run on login.

Also here's the link to github where this feature has been implemented by angular team - https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/8785b2bf6db8c3ecc4bd5edcf667d5f2f53f5271

Comment: I can see the point, but when I do log out I reset the state therefore the guard is false and it's triggered  when I do log in  so I dont se why the second one is not trigered again

Comment: please provide the code for the guards and login/logout. Even better if you can create a sample on stackblitz, it'll help in understanding what exactly is going wrong.